# Time series peak detection

Tags: time

I have time-series data from two sensors. I wanted to compare the peak number, width, height, and area under the peak of the sensors (time-based). Also, I tried to calculate the sensors' peak detection accuracy through the peak identification algorithm (by the cardidates and pracma packages). But I couldn't find a good algorithm. So please, could someone help me calculate the peak number, width, height, and area under the peak?

```
       DateTime ID CO CH4  H2 Temp  RH RawCH4 RawH2 ConvCH4 ConvH2
2022-11-18 14:39:17 01  0  65 260  334 302   1326   753    1326    753
2022-11-18 14:39:18 01  0  66 265  334 303   1313   749    1313    749
2022-11-18 14:39:19 01  0  67 267  334 303   1304   745    1304    745
2022-11-18 14:39:20 01  0  66 267  334 303   1277   741    1277    741
2022-11-18 14:39:21 01  0  65 267  334 304   1285   737    1285    737
2022-11-18 14:39:22 01  0  65 271  334 304   1281   734    1281    734
2022-11-18 14:39:23 01  0  64 269  334 304   1273   733    1273    733
2022-11-18 14:39:24 01  0  64 269  334 304   1264   729    1264    729
2022-11-18 14:39:25 01  0  64 271  334 304   1261   728    1261    728
2022-11-18 14:39:26 01  0  63 270  334 305   1260   726    1260    726
2022-11-18 14:39:27 01  0  64 270  334 305   1253   724    1253    724
2022-11-18 14:39:28 01  0  64 271  334 305   1253   722    1253    722
2022-11-18 14:39:29 01  0  63 271  334 304   1254   721    1254    721
```

Comment: Since you did not mention about any programming language, use MATLAB findpeaks to calculate local maxima. You can see the details of usage at
https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html